# Split by new line but skip if it is enclosed within quotes

Tags: javascript

I have some strings separated by new line(`\n`) and i want to split by `\n`
i am doing like this

```
const str = 'ab\ncd\nef\n"g\nh"'
const array = str.split('\n');
```

But this is also splitting `\n` within quotes. how can i skip the \n within quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` instead: either match match quotes eventually followed by another quote, or match any characters but newlines:

```js
const str = 'ab\ncd\nef\n"g\nh"';
const arr = str.match(/"[^"]*"|.+/g);
console.log(arr);
```

- `"[^"]*"` - Match a `"`, eventually followed by another `"
- `.+` - Match anything but newlines